# Algorithm to calculate the positions of bezier curve control point handles to transform from circle to straight line

Tags: geometry, algorithms, bezier-curve

From the image linked below (in A, I don't have enough points to add it directly) I have approximated two bezier cubic curve segments to a circle.
I know how to move the anchor points AP1 and AP3 along the bigger circle to the desired position using the following (for AP1 for 90 degrees):

```
    var zeroAngleDirection = (AP1 - AP2).normalized;

    var twist = Vector3(0, 0, angle);

    AP1 = AP2 + twist * zeroAngleDirection * Vector2.Distance(AP1, AP2);
```

I want to arrive at the straight line in red marked in B.
How can I rotate the control points as I reduce their length so that I'll arrive at the straight line, with AP1 = CP1 and so on?

[image: Bezier Curve Circle and straight line]

Please note that answers don't necessarily have to be in the same form as the code I provided above. I am just showing what I've been able to achieve so far.

Comment: Please, can someone help me out.

Comment: [Looks like you got your answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/167863/39518). You may want to delete the copy of the question, to avoid leaving a dead end for folks searching for similar answers.